# Embarcadero HTML5builder android MNotification how to use (code)

Tags: android, html5builder

I am using Embarcadero's HTML5Builder for Android server mobile apps development.

How can i use Mobile Hardware components, like: MNotification.

i need some useful code to use MNotification.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a value to the `Message` property from the Form Designer, and call `ComponentNameNotification()` from a JavaScript event, where `ComponentName` is the name of the MNotification component.

For example:

```
function MButton1JSClick($sender, $params)
{
    ?>
    //begin js
    MNotification1Notification();
    //end
    <?php
}
```

Note that hardware components only work inside PhoneGap. The notification will show in an application generated with the **Mobile Deployment** wizard, but not in a web browser.

Comment: What part of the answer haven’t you understood?!

Comment: MNotification1Notification(); - this function will init notification? how send some message with some title?

Comment: Yes, that function shows the notification. Use the properties of the MNotification1 component at design time to define the message, etc.

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work.. i compile it in html5builder->Deploy to mobile->..->..->PhoneGap.. it's correct? but what you talk about "Mobile Deployment wizard" - it some another software? sorry.. but please help me.. maybe you have some .apk and html5builder project? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

SO WHAT TO DO:

Download the SDK ADT Bundle for Windows
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Download PhoneGap
http://phonegap.com/download

And use this instructions:
1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCMXQGS_w
2) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO_59WXg33g

Thank's to all who trying to help me!